# I have a for loop to create a list, can I use a list comprehension instead?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let's have a list of values and an arbitrary integer number.

```
values = ['5', '3', '.', '.', '7', '.', '.', '.', '.', '6', '.', '.', '1', '9', '5', '.', '.', '.', '.', '9', '8', '.', '.', '.', '.', '6', '.', '8', '.', '.', '.', '6', '.', '.', '.', '3', '4', '.', '.', '8', '.', '3', '.', '.', '1', '7', '.', '.', '.', '2', '.', '.', '.', '6', '.', '6', '.', '.', '.', '.', '2', '8', '.', '.', '.', '.', '4', '1', '9', '.', '.', '5', '.', '.', '.', '.', '8', '.', '.', '7', '9']

n = 9
```

I'd like to group the values with `n` numbers in a row.

Let us suppose `n=9`, that is 9 numbers will be in a row.

The result should be like this:

```
grouped_values = [
     ['5', '3', '.', '.', '7', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
     ['6', '.', '.', '1', '9', '5', '.', '.', '.'],
     ['.', '9', '8', '.', '.', '.', '.', '6', '.'],
     ['8', '.', '.', '.', '6', '.', '.', '.', '3'],
     ['4', '.', '.', '8', '.', '3', '.', '.', '1'],
     ['7', '.', '.', '.', '2', '.', '.', '.', '6'],
     ['.', '6', '.', '.', '.', '.', '2', '8', '.'],
     ['.', '.', '.', '4', '1', '9', '.', '.', '5'],
     ['.', '.', '.', '.', '8', '.', '.', '7', '9']]
```

I can do it like this:

```
def group(values, n):
   rows_number = int(len(values)/n) # Simplified. Exceptions will be caught.
   grouped_values = []

   for i in range(0, rows_number):
      grouped_values.append(values[i:i+9])
```

But there is a suspicion that list comprehension can be used here.
Could you help me understand how can it be done?

Comment: Your own code doesn't produce the expected output; you produced `values[0:9]`, then `values[1:10]`, etc. instead of `values[0:9]`, `values[9:18]`, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Never trust them when they say they have a working solution :-P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just move the expression in the `list.append()` call to the front, and add the `for` loop:

```
grouped_values = [values[i:i + 9] for i in range(rows_number)]
```

Note that this does *not* slice up your input list into chunks of *consecutive* elements. It produces a *sliding window*; you slice `values[0:9]` then `values[1:10]`, etc. It produces windows onto the input data, each of length 9, with 8 elements overlapping with the previous window. To produce consecutive *chunks of length 9*, use `range(0, len(values), n)` as the range, no need to calculate `rows_number`:

```
grouped_values = [values[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(values), n)]
```

Whenever you see a pattern like this:

```
<list_name> = []

for <targets> in <iterable>:
    <list_name>.append(<expression>)
```

where `<expression>` does not reference `<list_name>`, you can trivially turn that into

```
<list_name> = [<expression> for <targets> in <iterable>]
```

The only difference here is that `list_name` is not set until *after* the whole list comprehension has been executed. You can't reference the list being built from inside the list comprehension.

Sometimes you need to move additional code in the loop body that produces that final `<expression>` value into a single expression before you arrive at the above pattern.

Note that it doesn't matter here that `<expression>` itself produces list objects; they can be entirely new list comprehensions or any other valid Python expression.

When there are more `for` loops or `if` statements with added nested levels, then list those added `for` loops and `if` statements from left-to-right in the resulting list comprehension; for example, the pattern

```
<list_name> = []

for <targets1> in <iterable1>:
    if <test_expression>:
        for <targets2> in <iterable2>:        
            <list_name>.append(<expression>)
```

becomes

```
<list_name> = [
    <expression>
    for <targets> in <iterable>
    if <test_expression>
    for <targets2> in <iterable2>
]
```